Strongswan VPN Client (Android) can't connect to my test Kerio Control server
I have the following issue: I set up a Kerio Control 9.4.4 build 8365 and tried to connect to VPN server through Android 14+ device. I used Strongswan(Android) for this, but I got the following error in the logs:
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[IKE] sending cert request for "C=JP, O=Japan Certification Services, Inc., CN=SecureSign RootCA11"
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[IKE] sending cert request for "C=GR, L=Athens, O=Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions Cert. Authority, CN=Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions RootCA 2015"
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[IKE] sending cert request for "C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=Starfield Technologies, Inc., CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2"
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[IKE] sending cert request for "CN=localcontrol, OU=it, O=test, L=test, ST=test, C=test"
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[IKE] authentication of 'CN=192.168.88.253, OU=it, O=test, L=test, ST=test, C=test' (myself) with RSA_EMSA_PKCS1_SHA2_256 successful
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[IKE] sending end entity cert "CN=192.168.88.253, OU=test, O=test, L=test, ST=test, C=test"
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[IKE] establishing CHILD_SA android{3}
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi CERT N(INIT_CONTACT) CERTREQ AUTH CPRQ(ADDR ADDR6 DNS DNS6) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(NO_ADD_ADDR) N(MULT_AUTH) N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) N(AUTH_FOLLOWS) ]
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[ENC] splitting IKE message (4428 bytes) into 4 fragments
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ EF(1/4) ]
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ EF(2/4) ]
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ EF(3/4) ]
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ EF(4/4) ]
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.88.10[49811] to 192.168.88.253[4500] (1360 bytes)
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.88.10[49811] to 192.168.88.253[4500] (1360 bytes)
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.88.10[49811] to 192.168.88.253[4500] (1360 bytes)
Mar 26 09:51:38 09[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.88.10[49811] to 192.168.88.253[4500] (544 bytes)
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[NET] received packet: from 192.168.88.253[4500] to 192.168.88.10[49811] (1248 bytes)
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(1/2) ]
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[ENC] received fragment #1 of 2, waiting for complete IKE message
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[NET] received packet: from 192.168.88.253[4500] to 192.168.88.10[49811] (192 bytes)
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(2/2) ]
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[ENC] received fragment #2 of 2, reassembled fragmented IKE message (1372 bytes)
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT AUTH ]
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[IKE] received end entity cert "CN=192.168.88.253, OU=it, O=test, L=test, ST=test, C=test"
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[CFG]   using trusted certificate "CN=192.168.88.253, OU=it, O=test, L=test, ST=test, C=test"
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[CFG]   using trusted ca certificate "CN=localcontrol, OU=it, O=test, L=test, ST=test, C=test"
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[CFG]   reached self-signed root ca with a path length of 0
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[CFG] checking certificate status of "CN=192.168.88.253, OU=it, O=test, L=test, ST=test, C=test"
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[CFG] certificate status is not available
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[IKE] authentication of 'CN=192.168.88.253, OU=it, O=test, L=test, ST=test, C=test' with RSA_EMSA_PKCS1_SHA2_256 successful
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 2 [ IDi ]
Mar 26 09:51:38 11[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.88.10[49811] to 192.168.88.253[4500] (76 bytes)
Mar 26 09:51:38 12[NET] received packet: from 192.168.88.253[4500] to 192.168.88.10[49811] (76 bytes)
Mar 26 09:51:38 12[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 2 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
Mar 26 09:51:38 12[IKE] received AUTHENTICATION_FAILED notify error

My topology:

PC acting as Kerio Control Server
Switch acting as DHCP server
Router (no Internet connection)
Main PC, where I access Kerio Control Web panel




I am almost certain my certificate is correct and I connect using Windows IKEv2 with certificate just fine.
What did I do wrong?
EDIT: Here is certificate info I got from openssl. For some reason I couldn't open the pkcs12 certificate, but I was able to open pem certificate and key



Can you post details about the server certificates (e.g. by using openssl x509 -text -noout). Also note that if the certificate does not contain the IP address as subjectAltName, you could configure the complete subject DN of the certificate as remote identity in the advanced profile settings on the client.

I edited the post, added certificate info

OK, thanks. The problem is that the subjectAltName in the certificate has the wrong type. Instead of DNS (which is for hostnames) it should be IP Address. And you shouldn't have posted the private key as you now have to create a new one. When you then issue the new certificate, make sure it contains a subjectAltName of type IP Address (optionally a second with type DNS if some clients require that). Or just use a hostname instead of an IP address (could make it easier if the IP address ever changes).

Thanks, I will try it

If you configure IKEv2 Certificate + EAP (Username/Password) as VPN type on the client, it will expect that the server initiates an EAP authentication after the client's initial certificate authentication (this uses an extension defined in RFC 4739, which isn't widely supported).
The server apparently isn't configured to do so (if it even supports this), so the authentication fails when the client sends a second IKE_AUTH request. If you want to authenticate the client with a certificate, then configure IKEv2 Certificate as VPN type.

Thank you for the information, but it still doesn't work
In the logs it throws the following errors:
Apr  2 12:01:00 16[CFG] constraint check failed: certificate does not confirm identity '192.168.88.253' (ID_IPV4_ADDR)
Apr  2 12:01:00 16[CFG] selected peer config 'android' unacceptable: constraint checking failed
Apr  2 12:01:00 16[CFG] no alternative config found

That happens if your server certificate doesn't contain that IP address as subjectAltName extension. Either update the certificate so it does, or configure the server identity to the complete subject DN of the certificate in the advanced profile settings on the client.

A bummer. My certificate should be fine, I connect to VPN on Windows using IKev2 protocol, installed certificate and Username+Password method. I assume either I installed certificate on my Android incorrectly or current version of Kerio doesn't support IKEv2

That Windows clients accept a certificate does not automatically mean strongSwan or other clients (like macOS/iOS) will do as well. Unlike Windows, strongSwan does not match the server's identity against parts of the subject DN (e.g. CN), only against  subjectAlternativeNames. So if there is no match, the certificate is clearly not "fine" for this use case.
